# Is it possible to select text from a pdf with a mouse in QPdfView class?

Tags: python, pdf, pyside6

I would like to select text using a mouse...I can't find anything in the documentation that enables this and also checked QpdfSelection class. Is it possible?

I tried right and left clicking on the mouse which doesn't work

Comment: No, you have to implement it yourself from the [bounds](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpdfselection.html#bounds-prop).

Comment: I should perhaps qualify my previous comment a little bit. The source code includes two [pdf examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtpdf-examples.html) - one widget-based, and the other qml-based. After compiling these, I found that (as of version 6.6.1) the former still has no selection, but the latter now *does* - although it's quite buggy, since the selection doesn't line up properly with the text. So it seems Qt's pdf classes are currently a work in progress and full selection support may eventually appear in a later release.